# Sending E-Mail in PHP

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I tried almost everything. I just want to send e-mail.

My First Code:

```
<?php
$to = "yourgmail@gmail.com";
$subject = "HELLO";
$body = "HI!";
try {
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

It isn't working. No error message, not working.

My Second Code:

```
function send_mail('mygmail@gmail.com','yourgmail@gmail.com','HELLO','HI!')
{
    $headers = '';
    $headers .= "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-to: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', time()) . "\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
}
```

It isn't working too.

Please help me :)

Comment: Looks like a hosting issue.

Comment: Are you using XAAMP or something similar? Or do you actually have hosting?

As an aside, I would recommend using PHPMailer https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: Are you calling the function?

Comment: @blo What function? Edit: The second code's function, yes. I am calling that function.

Comment: Just so you know - if you're using XAAMP, it will not actually send your email. You have to do some special configuration to get it to send email.

If you're using shared hosting, then it should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

First part:

```
<?php 

$to = "yourgmail@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "HELLO"; 
$body = "HI!"; 
$from = "mygmail@gmail.com";

send_mail($to,$from,$subject,$body);

?>
```

Second part:

```
<?php

function send_mail($to,$from,$subject,$body) { 

  $headers = ''; 
  $headers .= "From: $from\n"; 
  $headers .= "Reply-to: $from\n"; 
  $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\n"; 
  $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">\n"; 
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', time()) . "\n";

  mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

}

?>
```

I'm not sure if you can send mail via your gmail using php mail function, never looked into it, this should work for name@yourdomain.com

Comment: No, it isn't worked in my host. I found the problem anyway. Your code is working other hosts. +1! Thanks!